# Changing Dates as a string into actual Date types

Tags: r

I'm trying to change a column into a date type when it's currently a string. The format of each date looks like 20020101. I originally tried:

```
tempData$DATE = as.Date(tempData$DATE, "%Y%M%D")
```

and

```
tempData$DATE = as.Date(tempData$DATE, "%YYYY%MM%DD")
```

Both filled my column with `NA`s and I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. Obviously I'm relatively new to R still, but this seems like a simple fix or oversight on my part. Thanks!

Comment: It should (presumably) be `tempData$DATE = as.Date(tempData$DATE, "%Y%m%d")`. Note the capitalisation.

Comment: @MauritsEvers That seemed to be the issue. Thank you very much, didn't realize the capitalization made all of the difference.

Comment: Great, glad that solved it. You can find a summary of the various date placeholder symbols [here](https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html) and under `?strptime`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a package, try `lubridate`. It provides functions for date operations that are simple enough to remember and use. The date conversion algorithms are intelligent and more forgiving than the `as.date` base-R function.

**Installation:**

```
install.packages('lubridate')
```

**Import and convert:**

```
library(lubridate)
tempData$DATE = ymd(tempData$DATE)
```

**Example:**

```
> ymd('20020101')
[1] "2002-01-01"
```